# Reasons for Close - Title is not clickable

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

After the recent update its no longer possible to click the Reason and click Close. I have to click the Radio Button . Am I the only one facing it?

[image]

Comment: <nitpick>That's not a checkbox, that's a radio button</nitpick>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops ... sorry about that, fixed in dev

Answer (score 1):

Duplicated in FireFox 3.6.10 on this question.

Curiously the mouse turns into the clickable cursor as I mouse over the title, but clicking there causes no action.

Comment: The `label` has a `cursor: pointer` set to it in the CSS, causing the hand to appear - that behavior is not standard, and is actually independent of the focusing behavior. The `for` attribute which handles the focusing is pointing to a non-existent `input` element, causing this to fail.